# How to Validate users by SqlDataSource Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I make a Login page to validate user. I have a sql table like following:

table: **tblUsers**

```
userID (int is identity)
username (nvarchr (50))
password (nvarchr (50))
```

Login.ASPX

```
    Username<asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
    Password <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:Button ID="cmdLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" 
        onclick="cmdLogin_Click" /><br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Label><br />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConStr %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblUser] WHERE (([username] = @username) AND ([password] = @password))">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtPassword" Name="username" 
                PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtPassword" Name="password" 
                PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Validate users is in SelectCommand of SqlDataSource.

```
SELECT * FROM [tblUser] WHERE (([username] = @username) AND ([password] = @password))
```

how to validate user by SqlDataSource? I want code for Login button.

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.  More importantly, security is _hard_.  Don't reinvent the wheel.  You should use the built-in membership system.

Comment: Another comment: your SQLDataSource is getting so complex that it will probably do you well to start using the code-behind for your database interaction.  ADO.NET has classes that will give you more direct control over your interactions, and that you can put breakpoints to allow you to debug your more complex queries.  Highly suggested over using SQLDataSource in the markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected void cmdLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView dView = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    if (dView.Count == 1)
        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
    else
        lblError.Text="Incorrect username or password!";
}
```